# How to style admob in xml?

Tags: android, colors, admob

I am currently trying to theme an admob view and that work fine in Java code:

```
.addExtra("color_bg", "6D0504")
.addExtra("color_bg_top", "6D0504")
.addExtra("color_border", "6D0504")
.addExtra("color_link", "000080")
.addExtra("color_text", "808080")
.addExtra("color_url", "008000");
```

I could indeed make it work like this.

But i would like to work with xml and all the temptative I have tried have failed so far...

```
<com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     ads:adSize="BANNER"
     ads:adUnitId="XXX"
     ads:refreshInterval="60"/>
```

Something like

```
ads:color_bg="#6D0504"
```

does not work at all and I cannot find any inforùation in the official doc:
https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/best-practices#adcolors

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can style background and text color online in `AdMob>Sites&Apps>App Settings` (click [here](http://it.admob.com/my_sites/tools/?mt=sss) for direct link) and then setting `Ad style` to "use color set below:" where you can specify your own colors.
There are also some other interesting settings in that page, such as autorefresh rate.